# Fetch records from dataframe by calculating percentage of one column

Tags: python, calculation

There is a Dataframe in python as follow:

1. Serial Numbers 2. count of work order numbers

| Serial Nummbers | Work order numbers |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 16 |
| cde | 15 |
| def | 14 |
| efg | 14 |
| fgh | 12 |
| ghi | 10 |

Now the total sum of all the values of work order number is 91. Now I want to fetch all the records  whose work order number sum is 25%(81*0.25 = 20.25 ~ 20) of total sum. Similarly want to fetch 50% and 75% of sum of work order number column.

I tried using the following command but it isnt giving me the correct output:

dataframe_first50 = pd.DataFrame()
dataframe_first50 = dataframe_calculation1.nlargest(int(91*0.50), 'Work order numbers|', keep='first')
print(dataframe_first50)

I want a python code to resolve the above issue.

Comment: @ChemEnger Can you please help in this?

Comment: @PhE Can you please help?

Comment: @jezrael Can you please help?